# Unity: Duplicate Scene By Copy And Not Reference

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 'scene 1' in my Unity project.
I have made a duplicate of that as 'scene 2'.

When I make changes in 'scene 2' and save it, those changes are also reflected in 'scene 1'.

Changes such as replacing images.

[image]

How can I reuse 'scene 1' without it being linked to 'scene 2'?

Thanks

Comment: What type of changes are reflected in other scenes. It would be good to give an example and also put a screenshot of this

Comment: Hello, I agree more information would help. There is no reflection in scene changes, as I can see you're changing the material which not bound to a scene. In case if you want to have different images on one material you have to duplicate it and assign appropriately.

Comment: @zhekazheka How do I assign the material?

Comment: Hey, you can either drag and drop it on an object or drop it into the material property of the MeshRenderer.